# ValueError: Unknown activation function: LeakyReLU

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have constructed, fitted, and saved the following model:

```
def build_Lstm_model(train_x,train_y,test_x,test_y):
        inp = Input(shape=(train_x.shape[1],train_x.shape[2]))
        rnn_1st_model = LSTM(units=60, return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=0.1)(inp)
        rnn_2nd_model = LSTM(units=60,recurrent_dropout=0.1)(rnn_1st_model)
        dense_layer = Dense(128)(rnn_2nd_model)
        drop_out = Dropout(0.2)(dense_layer)
        output = Dense(1, activation= LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1),name="class")(drop_out)
        model = Model(inp, output)
        callbacks = [ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, factor=0.6),
                     EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20),
                     ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model_LSTM.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]
        model.summary()
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
        history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, 
              epochs = 8, 
              batch_size = 128, 
              validation_data=(test_x,  test_y), 
              callbacks=callbacks)
        return history,model
```

I am using the load_model function for deployment, and I am now getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function: LeakyReLU
```

Comment: try `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU`

Comment: See https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/leaky_relu/